# C# application fails to load DLL file in Windows 11

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, windows-11

I'm getting this exception on running my C# application, works fine on Windows 10.

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'OMSCommon64.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3K4j.png)

I tried to manually register the dll by following this article https://kb.blackbaud.com/knowledgebase/articles/Article/48280
but i get this error then
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TCWL.png)

Comment: Paste text instead a picture is a good start to improve a question.
Also, are you sure the windows11 machine have the OMScommon64.dll installed and/or registered?

Comment: @J.Salas I wasnt sure so i tried to register it using this command regsvr32 "C:\Users\qatest.TIX\Desktop\TiX Applications\Config client\1.10.8.0203\OMSCommon64.dll", but its unable to load the file.

Comment: Are you using an OMS database?   It was obsoleted in the 1980's and my company bought the source code for the database and has been maintaining it for years.  Did you attempt to rebuild the OMSCommon64 library?  Did you get any errors while attempting to build the library?  If DLL files are missing on your Windows 11/10/8/7 computer, the best ways to fix such errors are as follows:
1) Run the built-in System File Checker tool to replace missing or corrupted operating system files.
2) Run the DISM tool and repair the Windows system image and fix a corrupted Windows Component Store.

Comment: @jdweng _Are you using an OMS database? It was obsoleted in the 1980's_  

Comment: @jdweng No im not, its just the name of my library... I didnt rebuild the library cause i made no changes, but then I did and now its working on windows 11 too.
I dont get it, why is it working now?

Comment: You are probably using a different version of Net on Win11 from Win10.  When Net version changes you must always do a clean built to update the intermediate obj files.